# how can I prevent malloc.c 3096 sYSMALLOC: assertion failed while using fscanf to build an array from a port?

Tags: c, malloc, scanf, calloc

I'm writing a parsing program that receives data from a serial port, and I keep getting a "malloc.c 3096 sYSMALLOC assertion failed" upon execution. This is a very long code, and so for the simplicity of the reader I've only included the part where the issue is occurring. I can identify that the issue occurs somewhere due to writing values from the port into mdpu_parse using fscanf, as the code previously worked when I was just testing the structures using scanf to write values into the array and then store them in the structures. 
here is the code:

```
       #include <sdtio.h>
       #include <stdint.h>
       #include <stdlib.h>
       #include "mpdu_init.h"
       #define  BAUDRATE B115200
       #define  PORT "/dev/ttyS0"
       main(){

       char *mpdu_parse;
       char  npdu_parse[100];
       char  apdu_parse[500];
       FILE *fp;
       MPDU *mpdu = malloc(sizeof(mpdu));
       *mpdu = init_mpdu();

        mpdu_parse = calloc(7, sizeof(char));

       fp = fopen(PORT, "r+");
       check1: for(i=0 i< 7; i++){
                 fscanf(fp, "%02x", &mpdu_parse[i]);
                 }

           fclose(fp);


      if((mpdu_parse[0] == 0x55) && (mpdu_parse[1] == 0xFF)){

                    mpdu -> frame_type = mpdu_parse[2];
                    mpdu -> dest_addr = mpdu_parse[3];
                    mpdu -> source_addr = mpdu_parse[4];
                    mpdu -> length[0] = mpdu_parse[5];
                    mdpu -> length[1] = mpdu_parse[6];
                    mpdu -> data_crc = mpdu_parse[7];
                goto check1;
                }
                else if((mdpu_parse[0] != 0x55) || (mpdu_parse[1] != 0xFF)){
                                print("invalid message\n");
                                      goto check1;
                                 }
                           }
```

I understand that I have a memory issue somewhere, but i can not see what is causing the issue. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This defines seven elements:

```
mpdu_parse = calloc(7, sizeof(char));
```

where as this loops eight times:

```
for(i=0 i<=7; i++)
```

so this

```
fscanf(fp, "%02x", &mpdu_parse[i]);
```

access the array `mpdu_parse` out of bounds for th elast iteration.

To fix this either do

```
mpdu_parse = calloc(8, sizeof(char));
```

or

```
for(i=0 i<7; i++)
```